# Online databases for trying out Oracle SQL queries?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am studying for an undergraduate databases course.

I'd like to know if there are any online sites that allow me to do queries against an already built and populated database (with a known schema), so I didn't have to install SQL and populate it with data myself.

I am currently doing some exercises by hand on a workbook I have here, but I'm a bit afraid that I might be doing them wrong and it's hard to check their correctness without testing them against the "real thing".

Thanks

(In our course we are using Oracle)

Comment: BTW, SQL Server comes with several fully populated DB's you can simply download and install

Comment: And SQL Server Express is free.

Comment: Try this: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). This is simply the best ;)

Comment: We created this video tutorial for SQL Fiddle to help understand the basics and how it helps the beginner users to learn SQL [SQL Fiddle Video Tutorial](http://allzhere.in/2013/03/12/sql-fiddle-runexecute-sql-online/)

Comment: I think this is a valid question. Admins really didn't need to close the question -- I don't see how his desire to experiment in SQL will solicit debate, arguments, etc... Admins on this site are way to controlling of information...

Comment: It is a valid question... just not a good fit for the site. In this case I would have tagged it closed for "asking fora n offsite tool or library" -> which is clearly marked as one of the reasons to close questions. Sorry. Close-reasons aren't just to be mean to people. All of the close-reasons have been added for very good reasons (ie they have been shown to cause problems for the site in the past that outweigh the benefits of the occasional useful question).

Comment: Another such option is this link from [Tutorial Point Oracle 11g](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/oracle_terminal_online.php)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you tried [SQLZoo](http://sqlzoo.net/) ?

You can (for free) install [SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/), and download and install already populated databases (such as AdventureWorks2008) from [here](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55926). Both installs are straight forward.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to go far, do try the [StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new):

> About
>
> Stack Exchange Data Explorer allows you to run arbitrary queries on the Stack Exchange public data dumps.

It's fast and supports a SQLServer-like T-SQL syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Give Stack Exchange's [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) a spin.

---

For Oracle specific queries, you can signup for [Oracle's Apex](http://apex.oracle.com/) which gives you a pre-populated schema based on the Employees/Departments table

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, by SQLZoo Tutorials allow you to practice some basic interactions, and also allow you to interact with a number of different SQL Engines.

http://sqlzoo.net/

Answer (score 2):

You can easily install MySQL/PostgreSQL/SQL Server Express and get up and running, also whatever test data might be installed on a publicly available server won't  necessarily stay the same between queries, since anyone can access it.

So just go ahead and install one of the above, you'll thank yourself in the near future.

Comment: SQL Server Express is extremely easy to install and get running.

Comment: Seems that a lot changed since that time, was not able to install it properly (have limited admin rights on my office pc) and was nbot able to uninstall it completely. Or this is sarcasm?

Comment: I would recommend PostgreSQL unless you have a very specific reason not to.

Answer (score 2):

Try out [this Interactive SQL](http://sqlzoo.net/) site. It looks what are you looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing [WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).  This comes with MySQL and a UI of phpMyAdmin that you can use to install and test databases.  Then you can install the MySQL [test employees database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/employee.html).

Answer (score 0):

For very simple queries, you can try SQL queries online in the W3Schools SQL Try It page - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_tryit.asp

Or you can use the online demo of phpMyAdmin at http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/?pma_username=root for deeper use.

Comment: There is just one table there. Almost useless.

Comment: added new link to phpMyAdmin demo server in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Apex provides online space for you to create and execute your sql queries. Please create an account with Oracle Apex and then enjoy with your personalised tablespace and schema. This is freeware and Oracle doesn't charge anything for this. It is the best way if you don't want to install Oracle on your system and don't want to slow down your system. Another advantage of Oracle Apex is that you have all your tables and data online and you don't have to maintain it, Oracle will do that for you. You can access your database from anywhere you want.